# JPOS testing (Functional and Perf ) using Apache Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to perform functional test of JPOS based ISO message and response(TPS) using Jmeter.Can anyone guide me on this?Do I need to install any plugin in Jmeter.As I have tried to install the Jmeter in my system.But Can't see any Jpos plugin in listeners to start with.Dev is Using Socket connection in Jpos.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to find any plugin, however you should be able to use [jPOS](http://www.jpos.org/) client library from the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)

1. [Download the jPOS](http://www.jpos.org/download) and build it using [Gradle](https://gradle.org/)
2. Copy `jpos/build/libs/jpos-x.x.x.jar` to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (along with dependencies, if you don't have them yet)
3. Restart JMeter to pick the library up
4. Add JSR223 Sampler to your Test Plan and put the code, implementing your test scenario into "Script" area, an example would be something like:

   ```
   import org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg
   import org.jpos.iso.channel.ASCIIChannel
   import org.jpos.iso.packager.ISO87APackager

   def host = 'your_host'
   def port = 1234

   def channel = new ASCIIChannel(host, port, new ISO87APackager())
   channel.connect()
   def message = new ISOMsg()
   message.setMTI("0800")
   message.set(3, "000000")
   message.set(41, "00000001")
   message.set(70, "301")
   channel.send(message)
   ISOMsg response = channel.receive()
   channel.disconnect()
   ```

More information:

- [jPOS Programmer’s Guide](http://jpos.org/doc/proguide-draft.pdf)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T for your thoughts.I have clarifications though.I am using Java 1.8 and Jmeter 3.3.So what version of Jpos jar is required.Dev team has already coded for Jpos client and Jpos server.They have also complied jar in local.Should I take that Jar or in general I need to download JPOS to my local Intellij and then build using gradle to convert Jars.I need to connect the Jpos server via Jmeter (act as a client)which is sending ISO8583 message via request and getting response .Then to validate the functionally and getting the throughput (Transactions per seconds).Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We can send a XML or rawMessage to jpos server from the Jmeter TCPSampler

- You can also add TPS listeners

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmGUW.png)

And JPosTCPClient can be implemented

```
public class JPosTCPClient extends TCPClientImpl {
private static final Logger log = LoggingManager.getLoggerForClass();

private String containsString = "</isomsg>";
private boolean filterEnabled = true;

public JPosTCPClient() {
    filterEnabled = Boolean.parseBoolean(JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("jpos.tcp.use", "true"));
    containsString = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("jpos.tcp.contains", "</isomsg>");
}


/**
 * Reads data until the defined EOL byte is reached.
 * If there is no EOL byte defined, then reads until
 * the end of the stream is reached.
 */
@Override
public String read(InputStream is) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    ByteArrayOutputStream w = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int x = 0;
    boolean contains = false;
    try {
        while ((x = is.read(buffer)) > -1) {
            w.write(buffer, 0, x);
            if(filterEnabled){
                String response = new String(buffer);
                if(response.contains(containsString)){
                    contains = true;
                    break;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Contents: " + response);
                }
            }
        }
        if(filterEnabled && !contains){
            System.out.println("Skipped containsString checking, x length:" + x);
        }

    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        // drop out to handle buffer
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
        // drop out to handle buffer
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        log.warn("Read error:" + e);
        return "";
    }

    // do we need to close byte array (or flush it?)
    log.debug("Read: " + w.size() + "\n" + w.toString());
    return w.toString();
}
```

}